# VueJS and Laravel Blade - incrementing counter in nested v-for loops

Tags: laravel, increment, laravel-blade, vue.js

I am using v-for to create a list of people from an object, each with a number assigned. Here is a simplified example:

home.js:

```
data: function () {
        return {
            agegroups: {
                adult: 3,
                child: 1,
                infant: 2
            }
        }
    },
```

home.blade.php:

```
<ul>
    <template v-for="(num, agegroup) in agegroups">
        <li v-for="index in num">
            @{{ index }}
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

This produces 1 2 3 1 1 2

However, I want it to produce 1 2 3 4 5 6

How can this be done? It seems like it can easily be achieved with a simple counter, but where do I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/7o4k0gf2/

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted () {
    var sum = 0
    for (const key of Object.keys(this.agegroups)) {
      sum += this.agegroups[key]
        this.offset.push(sum)
        }
  },
  data: {
    agegroups: {
      adult: 3,
      child: 1,
      infant: 2
    },
    offset: [0]
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
    <template v-for="(num, agegroup, idx) in agegroups" v-init="getOffset(num)">
      <li v-for="index in num">
         {{offset[idx] + index}}
      </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
```

I had to create a variable which is pre populated based on `agegroups` to keep track of earlier indexes, and I add this to index of nested for loop.